# Error CS0433: The type 'JsonValue' exists in both 'System.Json, Version=2.0.5.0' and 'Xamarin.Auth' (CS0433)

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth, system.json

I'm trying to create an app in Visual studio for mac with Xamarin.Forms. In this app I'm using Xamarin.Auth to store some user details. Now I want to add a connection with an API by using JSON. I added System.Json and added my code. But the problem is I get the error:

> Error CS0433: The type 'JsonValue' exists in both 'System.Json,
>   Version=2.0.5.0' and 'Xamarin.Auth' (CS0433).

I removed and added Xamarin.Auth to the project. I removed the OBJ and BIN folders while visual studio was closed, started VS, cleaned the solution, rebuild the solution and tried it again but still the same error. I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

I'm not quite sure if it will help but here is one snippet of code where the error occurs, I know the function does not return anything at the moment but I'm just trying to figure out how to do JSON/API calls and get the code to compile without errors:

```
public class DBhandler
{
    public async Task<List<Object>> GetItemsFromApiASync(Type callingClass,    string apiDir, string apiFile)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ApiAddress + apiDir + apiFile));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "Get";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                System.Json.JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => System.Json.JsonObject.Load(stream));
                object[] parametersArray = new object[] { jsonDoc };
                MethodInfo methodInfo = callingClass.GetMethod("ConvertApiResultToObject");
                methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Fully-qualify your class (i.e. include the namespace) usage so that the compiler knows which one you intended to use.

Comment: Try set outside your namespace `using JsonValue = System.Json.JsonValue` and remove the qualifyed uses from method

Comment: Use the alias feature of the */reference* compiler option

Comment: @Tcraft I've added the Alias to the reference in Visual Studio. Then using extern alias gives me the `the extern alias was not specified in a reference option` which I can't seem to solve.

@DiegoRafaelSouza I've tried that, it gives me the same error.

@KennethK. I'm not sure what you mean. I already fully specified the class(System.Json.JsonValue). My class has a namespace but was left out in this code snippet.

An extra fun fact: in one class I'm using `using SystemJsonAlias = System.Json` which compiles. In other classes I'm using the same but I get the `exists in both` error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of a sudden I did remember how to solve this: I was helped by the comments on the question(thanks @Tcraft, @DiegoRafaelSouza). I added `System.Json` to the references on the different platforms(I use a shared project, so on `project.IOS` and `project.Android`). Right clicked on `properties` and ticked `Local Copy`. Then I added an alias `SystemJsonAlias`. And used `using SystemJsonAlias = System.Json` in all my .cs files where needed.

Perhaps this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem when creating a Xamarin Android project that referenced Xamarin.Auth and a few other NuGet packages and the Facebook Xamarin component. I was able to simply remove System.Json from my project's references, and then my project was able to compile and run.

Comment: That was not an option for me. I needed to use System.Json. I eventually got it working with a lot of fiddling and luck and using `using SystemJsonAlias = System.Json` Don't ask me how cause I can't replicate it at the moment(too long ago and not quite sure what I did) but it works, so I leave it.